# Cannot override the CSS at this site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This site is overriding my CSS with its own and I cannot get around it! It has style.css with `"text-align: center"` in the body.

I have `<div id="mydiv">` appended to the body and it's normally got "text-align: left". There are `<ul>`s and `<li>`s underneath #mydiv and they are inheriting the body's 'center' for some reason. I tried this and it's still not working.

```
$('#mydiv').children().css('text-align', 'auto');
```

How the heck do I reclaim my CSS!?

@Grillz, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<ul class="container">
    <li rel="folder" class="category"><a href="#">category1</a>
        <ul><li rel="file" class="subcategory"><a href="#">subcategory1</a></li></ul>
        <ul><li rel="file" class="subcategory"><a href="#">subcategory2</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li rel="folder" class="category"><a href="#">category2</a>
        <ul><li rel="file" class="subcategory"><a href="#">subcategory3</a></li></ul>
        <ul><li rel="file" class="subcategory"><a href="#">subcategory4</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: we need an example to start with most likely. also, have you tried adding in the !important modifier to your jQuery?  also, auto is not in the approved methods for text-align..          and you could try            $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').css('text-align', 'left !important');
});

Comment: You should give this a read: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it via jQuery, your `.children()` is only selecting the `<ul>`, not the `<li>`... You need to do something like this:

```
$('#mydiv').children().children().each(function() {
    $(this).css('text-align', 'left');
});
```

Firstly, its drilling down two levels, down to the `<li>`. Secondly its using the `.each()` function to apply the css styling to each child...

**EDIT:** after seeing your html above, below is probably more appropriate:

```
$('#mydiv').find("li").each(function() {
    $(this).css('text-align', 'left');
});
```

This uses the `.find()` function to find every `<li>` element inside `#myDiv`.

Working jsFiddle (with color instead of text-align) here: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/Vabvu/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/gdanko/PrGWU/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/gdanko/PrGWU/1/) seems to work

Comment: That did the trick. Is there a way to prevent the body from overriding the font family? I don't know which font-family the jquery ui css is trying to use and I don't want to hard code it. Is there a way to read what font information is being provided by the jquery ui theme? That way I can apply it to all li items.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a more specific css rule. Something like this will set text alignment to left for all the children of #mydiv.

```
body #mydiv * {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without children() function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').css('text-align', 'left !important');
});
```

and I'm guessing you trued to insert `<UL/>` and `<LI/>` in your example. you need to define them as code for them to show up

Comment: If I changed <a> to use class subcategory, couldn't I do $('.subcategory).css('text-align', 'left') ?